# find the game SDL ball to download

Tags: games, sdl

i have just been able to reinstall linux as duel boot and again my very favorite game sdlball has disappeared from the software list.
last time i reinstalled ubuntu someone here gave me usable steps to reinstall the game.

anyone, please email me with steps to reinstall sdlball, if possible

thanks

Comment: Please open a terminal window, enter the command `sudo apt install sdl-ball` and append any error messages to your question.

Comment: very easy to add per your command